# Set div padding z-index

Tags: css, html, particles.js

Is it possible to set the `z-index` of the padding of a specific `div`?

I'm using *particle.js* as an interactive background that changes with mouse position. However, this only works when the canvas is at the top of the stack. I am using a div container for the main content with a `padding` of `10%`.

I'd like this `padding` to be sent backwards on the stack so that the mouse can interact with the background.

Comment: Change the `padding` to `margin` to interact with its background, that way the space between the element and its parent is not intractable via the child element.

Comment: @Randy I've just changed the padding to margin but it still isn't allowing an interaction

Comment: Can you show an example of this in action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I managed to solve this by removing the padding and margins of the div and using relative position with the same spacings as the margin previously. I then set the canvas z-index to 1 with the container div z-index to 2.